# Subset data in groups based on column values

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr, subset

The following data are grouped by their id's. I am trying to subset this data frame per the following conditions: For any id that has `D2 == 1` delete rows below the row where we first observed this. Secondly, for any id with `D1 == 0` and `D2 == 0` delete rows below this point (if there's no `D2 == 1` prior to this point for this id).

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
            A=c(3,6,2,5,4,3,8,9,8),
           D1=c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0),
           D2=c(1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1))
```

I have considered this

```
df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
filter(...)
```

but it is not clear to me how to complete the `filter` function to perform this task. I expect the output to look like

```
  id A D1 D2
1  1 3  0  1
2  2 5  1  0
3  2 4  1  0
4  2 3  0  1
5  3 9  0  0
```

I appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rationale behind the `filter` in this solution is: for each `id`, for the rows where the condition inside `ifelse` is verified, we increment by 1 a temporary counter; therefore, for each `id` we want then to filter only those rows where this temporary counter is less or equal than 1 (so takes only values 0 and 1).

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(cumsum(ifelse(D2 == 1 | (D1 == 0 & D2 == 0), 1, 0)) <= 1)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
#      id     A    D1    D2
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     3     0     1
# 2     2     5     1     0
# 3     2     4     1     0
# 4     2     3     0     1
# 5     3     9     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Find first row that satisfy one of your conditions and take all rows before (including first one that satisfy condition). If none of the rows satisfy given conditions then take all rows:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(
    match(TRUE, D2 == 1 | (D1 == 0 & D2 == 0), nomatch = n()) %>% seq_len()
  )
```